# ROR3 'Rails Server' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I took a break away from a ROR3 project and came back to it after a few months. I ran the MacPorts update and then 'Rails Server' to kick things off and am getting this error. I then ran 'bundle install' as it looks like a Gem issue and the same error message came up. Can anyone shed any light on why it is happening now and a possible solution?

```
user$ rails console
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
  from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
  from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
  from /opt/local/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
user$
```

Comment: install gem rails: `gem install rails`

Comment: I've read a few blog posts from people running away from macports in the last few weeks and jumping into RVM and homebrew, because of problems on mac (specially on OSX Lion). I've been using RVM for quite some time now and it's been quite a good experience.

Comment: @narkoz That solution doesn't solve the issue!

Comment: Use RVM. Set up a gemset for your project, run `bundle install` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @jergason - thanks, but don't know anything about using RVM! Am getting error 'Could not find linecache-0.43 in any of the sources'. The plot thickens....

Comment: Google "Install RVM". It will save you headaches to learn about it in the long run. Installation is not difficult, and it prevents these kinds of nasty problems.

Comment: @Jergason Should I be remove MacPorts and install RVM instead? Or does it run 'alongside'? Will it solve the issue I'm currently having?

Comment: You can install it alongside MacPorts. It looks like the issue you are currently having is that your gems were removed in the MacPorts upgrade, so it should fix it. Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

With Time Machine installed I was able to drop the 'local' folder from when I knew Ruby On Rails was last working and everything is now fine again. MacPorts users beware and think about installing RVM as suggested!